# How to install VMWare Workstation 16 on Fedora Silverblue 36

Tags: fedora, rpm, vmware

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/fedora-how-tos/how-to-install-vmware-workstation-pro-on-fedora.html) on installing VMWare Workstation 16 on Fedora 36. I'm using Fedora Silverblue, however, and I'm running into several issues.

I first tried using Distrobox to create a containerized environment to work in and install stuff but that failed because any message/error boxes spawned by VMWare only had the "unknown character" symbol (the empty square).

I then tried to install it directly without a container, replacing any `dnf` call with `rpm-ostree` and rebooting properly. Here I ran into the issue that `/etc/init.d` does not exist.

How can I install VMWare Workstation on Fedora 36? I understand that VMWare does not officially support Fedora >33 but I would really prefer to not have to go back to Ubuntu.

Thanks!

Comment: uff, depending on /etc/init.d in 2022 is... ambitiously obsolete? Systemd has been booting systems since at least 2010, in the case of Fedora.

Comment: I honestly don't know whether using an unsupported distro *can* work at all – vmware needs its own kernel module, and I can't tell whether they've ported it to the F36 kernel.

Comment: I see... alright then, back to Ubuntu I go :(